# Upgraded to Bootstrap 4 - still serving Bootstrap v3 in ASP.Net MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have Boostrap v4 script files installed in my project ~/Content and ~/Script folders, but when run my project uses Boostrap v3! Why, and how to force it to use v4?

It is an MVC 5 project contained in a solution with a UWP project. I have upgraded the MVC project to Bootstrap v4, which has updated all of the Bootstrap files to v4. I'm not using a CSS preprocessor. My BundleConfig.cs is unchanged, and seems to load whatever version is found in the ~/Scripts folder:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

But when run, if I interogate the HTML then the bootstrap file served is v3:

[image]

When run, Visual Studio generates a temporary "Script Documents" folder underneath the parent solution for displaying "client-side script files generated from server-side scripts" - and the Bootstrap file loaded here is v3:

[image]

I noticed that the upgrade to v4 did not download updated versions of the boostrap-theme.css/.css.map/.min/.min.css.map files - but pages and elements load fine with these files removed from the project so I think its unrelated.

**After updating the Bootstrap script files to v4, what other configurations are required for ASP.Net MVC to load Bootstrap v4 script files from it's project ~/Content and ~/Script files?**

Comment: have you deleted the v3 files?

Comment: Yep, they've been overwritten. I can't find any trace of v3 in any files except for in 'Bootraps.in.js' and 'bootstrap.min.js.map' files, which start with "{"version":3,"file":"bootstrap.js"...". But changing these to version 4 doesn't solve it.

Comment: I tell a lie, I'd only tried changing the "version:3" strings to "version:4" in script files that referenced Boostrap, but you motivated me to try an industrial 'replace all' on all files. *This has updated the bootstrap version to 4!* The replace all updated a lot of files relating to popper. The blanket replace all has affected the page from loading so the solution must be somewhere in the middle - I'll report back when I've found the goldilocks list of files. Thanks for the prod, @ADyson

Comment: No, its a little weirder than that - it does now load a v4 Boostrap.js file but it also loads the old v3 file, and the v3 file is the one served to the page. Hmm.

Comment: could it be that what's served to the page is cached in the webserver and/or the browser? Try clearing your cache

Comment: @ADyson Yes, disabling the cache has resolved this - thanks so much! Now I can appreciate just how non-backwards compatible Bootstrap 4 really is with my broken layout - huzzah!

Comment: lucky you, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the browser cache did it for me